# Can we learn to adapt to image-reversal when being intermittently exposed to them?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, vision, perceptual-learning

I know that human vision can get accustomed to reverse vision when wearing reverse glasses for several days. But does it work when we see the reverse image just in certain moments throughout the day? Would it be easier or more difficult for humans to learn use a reverse mirror?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wearing prism glasses needs adaptation of behavior. That takes time. Wearing them during all waking hours speeds up the process as it forces the wearer to adapt in everyday life. If the subject does not adapt quickly, it's going to be a very hungry, un-showered, immobile and eventually a very unhappy subject, because tasks of daily living become pretty much impossible without adapting to the prisms.

Putting them on for an hour or so per day will not force the subject to cope with it. And even if a training regimen is commenced in that hour, when the subject puts them off the learning process stops. Eventually they may get there, but it is certainly not as effective.

Comment: I think mentioning the prism glasses was misleading for what I'm after. I wanted to ask, wheter it would be tougher for humans to learn to work with a mirror **from their childhood** if mirrors actually didn't reverse the image but now I realize that there won't be many differences since we learn many  seemingly natural skills that actually require coordination of movements, many times in the opposite direction than the operated objects move to (like cycling)

Comment: @Probably please feel free to ask another more targeted question! Further, my answer here is unreferenced and perhaps others can jump in to add their views. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure my realization that we could learn to work with not-reverse mirror just fine, just like we can [learn to bike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFzDaBzBlL0) clearly dilutes the problem.